# How do I implement a generic stack in C#?

Tags: c#, stack

I'm using Visual C# to program an RPN calculator using Stack. Problem is I don't know how to do this. I'm using System.Collections.Generic, but

```
Stack<double> s = new Stack<double>();
```

generates the error:

> Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack' requires '1' type arguments

I'm pretty clueless here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @CMS I didn't add the Stack<double> stuff in there. It was already there from @matt, it just wasn't showing up till I added four spaces to the front to move it to a code block.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Stack<int> s = new Stack<int>();
```

Replace int with whatever type you are storing in the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the type of the elements that you will store on your stack, for example a stack of integers:

```
Stack<int> s = new Stack<int>();
```